# Angular 2 passing object with @Output to another comp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a favorite button to update my ionic-side menu. I have been trying to use the @output decorator which might be wrong. In order to use @output does one of the two components have to be child component with html directive in the parent? Or can I pass data to another component without changing views this way?

Comment: Yup `@Output` is explicitly used for child component to interact with its parent. To communicate between 2 separate components, use common service.

Answer (score 0):

@input and @output need child-parent relationships. You can use services or observables to communicate with other components outside the child-parent relationship. Services seem to be popular because of Angular 1 but you could use whatever you like.